# Multiple for loops (not nested) in Django Template and the second one not working

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm facing the following problem:

On the view.py I send to the view template a list, such as:

```
return render(request, 'template.html', {'images': list})
```

Then on the template I make a for like:

```
{% for img in images %}
{{ img }}
{% endfor %}
```

and on other part of the template again I do:

```
{% for img in images %}
{{ img }}
{% endfor %}
```

but this second time the code doesn't even enter inside the loop, it looks like the cursor of the for is pointing to the last element of the array, is that right? how to fix it, I mean, move this cursor to the first position, supposing this is the case.

Comment: looks like `images` is a generator. What does `type(images)` return?

Comment: Thank you, Marat. Your Answer/question was my answer. I was passing a map to the template, I just made a type cast to list and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

convert the images context dictionary to a value. When you pass the images
variable its type is a python object. For instance in your views (SQL database):

---

```
    images= cursor.execute("SELECT * from images").fetchall()

    context={'images':images}

    **AND DO THIS IN YOUR TEMPLATE**

    {% for img in images %}
    {{ img }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for img in images %}
    { img }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: With Django, you don't really have to write SQL code. Sometimes you have to, but not really for the simple stuff.